# Email registration not working inside the fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, fragment

I'm currently developing a mobile app as my final project for this sem. So yeah, in my mobile app, I have this sign-up registration using email by using firebase. Here's the tutorial I followed to do this function (if you're interested).

[Firebase Login & Register App With Email | Part - 6 | Register User]

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPv7auErERo&list=PLlGT4GXi8_8dm7OeLB5SiVZAPXeSq9i2Z&index=6)

I already worked out this in an activity that is also used in the tutorial. But this time, I want to apply it to the fragment. My problem is after to fill up the required field and press the "Register" button, my app crashes. The button should open new activity.

Here are the following codes:

SIGNUP TAB FRAGMENT

```
package com.example.biowit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SignupTabFragment extends Fragment{

EditText sup_email, sup_fullname, sup_pass, sup_conpass;
Button btn_signup;
String fullname, email, password, conpassword;
FirebaseAuth su_FbAuth;
float v=0;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.signup_fragment, container, false);

    sup_fullname = root.findViewById(R.id.input_SU_fullname);
    sup_email = root.findViewById(R.id.input_SU_email);
    sup_pass = root.findViewById(R.id.input_SU_pass);
    sup_conpass = root.findViewById(R.id.input_SU_conpass);
    btn_signup = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_SUp);

    sup_email.setTranslationX(800);
    sup_fullname.setTranslationX(800);
    sup_pass.setTranslationX(800);
    sup_conpass.setTranslationX(800);
    btn_signup.setTranslationX(800);

    sup_email.setAlpha(v);
    sup_fullname.setAlpha(v);
    sup_pass.setAlpha(v);
    sup_conpass.setAlpha(v);
    btn_signup.setAlpha(v);

    sup_email.animate().translationX(0).alpha(1).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(300).start();
    sup_fullname.animate().translationX(0).alpha(1).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(300).start();
    sup_pass.animate().translationX(0).alpha(1).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(300).start();
    sup_conpass.animate().translationX(0).alpha(1).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(300).start();
    btn_signup.animate().translationX(0).alpha(1).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(300).start();

    btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //extract the data

            fullname = sup_fullname.getText().toString();
            email = sup_email.getText().toString();
            password = sup_pass.getText().toString();
            conpassword = sup_conpass.getText().toString();

            if(fullname.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                sup_fullname.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if(email.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                sup_email.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if(password.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                sup_pass.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if(conpassword.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                sup_conpass.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if (!conpassword.equals(password)){ // condition if the confirm password is not equals to password,
                sup_conpass.setError("Password does not match."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Validated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            su_FbAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) { // send the user to the log - in screen.

                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), HomeScreen.class));
                }

            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { // an error when email and pass is wrong or invalid.

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return root;
        //sign-up to home screen intent
    }
}
```

HOME SCREEN (The activity I talked/specified about)

```
package com.example.biowit;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

Button Chap1_btn, Achieve_btn, HowToPlay_btn, LogOut_btn, Settings_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    Chap1_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_Chap1);
    Achieve_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_Achievements);
    HowToPlay_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_HowToPlay);
    LogOut_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_Logout);
    Settings_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_Settings);

    Chap1_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent open_Chap1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LessonScreen.class);
            startActivity(open_Chap1);
        }
    });

    Settings_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent open_Settings = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Settings.class);
            startActivity(open_Settings);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the ERROR LOG:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.biowit, PID: 28881
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.biowit.SignupTabFragment$1.onClick(SignupTabFragment.java:97)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7504)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7476)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28651)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never instantiated the FirebaseAuth object.

You usually don't need to make a field for it, as it's a Singleton that will always give the same object

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`